# Jekyll index.html that uses 3 different _layouts

Tags: jekyll

I have 3 different _layouts.

- post-link.html
- post-article.html
- post-photo.html

I can show all my post on the index.html but they all have the same layout. Can I somehow show multiple layouts on the same page (index.html)?

Answer (score 20):

A page can have only one `layout`, but layouts can be nested.

I have three `_layouts`:

- master.html
- default.html
- post.html

The `master` layout has all of the basic structure that any page I want will need. It looks
something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

I use the `default` layout for most pages that are not blog posts. I do make extensive use
of a few `page` variables in pages' YAML front matter. The layout looks something like this:

```
---
layout: master
---
<h1>
  {{ page.title }}
  {% if page.subtitle %}<small>{{ page.subtitle }}</small>{% endif %}
</h1>
{% if page.description %}<p>{{ page.description }}</p>{% endif %}
{{ content }}
```

I use the `post` layout for `_posts` pages. It looks like this:

```
---
layout: default
---
<p>Posted {{ page.date }}</p>
<ul>{% for tag in page.tags %}...{% endfor %}</ul>
{{ content }}
```

Every blog post that I make, I use the `post` layout, and they inherit from all three layouts.

If you want to have snippets of reusable markup, then I would recommend using
[`_includes`](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Liquid-Extensions).

Answer (score 2):

A page can only have one layout. What you need is _includes, which you can use wherever a post is to be displayed.

Comment: I'll look into it. It seems like _includes are used more for things like headers, footers and sidebars but I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the advice.